# trouble printing pointers to void on structure

Tags: c, pointers, printing, void-pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct elem{

    void * d;

}Elem;

main(){

    Elem *p;
    Elem e;

    double pi = 3.14;

    e.d = &pi;
    p->d = &pi;

    printf("%f\n",p->d);
    printf("%f\n",e.d);


}
```

main.c:25: warning: format ‘%f’ expects type ‘double’, but argument 2 has type ‘void *’

main.c:26: warning: format ‘%f’ expects type ‘double’, but argument 2 has type ‘void *’

I'm having trouble trying to print this values correctly.
I'm getting values that got nothing to do with 3.14.

Comment: `*(float*)e.d` or `*(float*)p->d`

Comment: @im also UB. `%f` takes a double. It is also UB because the object it points to is a `double`. That violates strict aliasing rule.

Answer (score 4):

In your code, first, you need to allocate memory to `p` before dereferencing it. Otherwise, it invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Otherwise, `p` is an unitialized pointer and points to a memeory, which may not be accessible from your program, thereby, essentially, an invalid memory location. Any attempt to dereference that pointer will invoke UB.

After that,

```
  printf("%f\n",p->d);
  printf("%f\n",e.d);
```

invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), as you're essentially trying to print an address with `%f` format specifier.

What you have to do, is to

1. cast the `void` pointer to `float` pointer (beacuse, you cannot dereference a `void *`)
2. and then, derererence the pointer to get the value.

Like

```
  printf("%f\n",*((float *)(p->d)));
  printf("%f\n",*((float *)e.d));
```

That said, `main()` should be `int main(void)`, at least, to be standard complaint.

Comment: *What you have to do, is to cast the pointer to `float`*......because you can't dereference a `void` pointer.

Comment: @haccks Yes sir, that's what I meant to write. Did my wordings mean otherwise?

Comment: No. I just suggested to add that in your answer. Waiting to vote up.

Comment: @haccks Thank you. :)

Comment: You're welcome. You can also [consider accepting an answer that helped you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/244062).

Answer (score 2):

You can't do:

```
Elem *p;
[...]
double pi = 3.14;
[...]
p->d = &pi;
```

...because `p` points nowhere. At best your program behavior will be undefined, but at most it will crash. Correct code to do what I think you want to achieve is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct elem {
    void * d;
} Elem;

int main(void) {
    double pi = 3.14;
    // make p point to allocated memory
    Elem *p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
    p->d = &pi;
    // notice the %lf and *(double *)
    // %f is for floats, %lf is four doubles
    // and *(double *) means 'use the value of the pointer (the d field)
    // as the pointer to double type. And then use the value it points to
    printf("%lf\n", *(double *)(p->d));
    return 0;
}
```